# Assistance in adding an unknown function. (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and am going over an online tutorial. I am attempting to modify one of the short programs it asks me to create. Eventually I will learn the following, but I am interested in it at this moment.

It's a simple simulation program about dropping a ball off a tower (assuming negligible air resistance and change in gravity), and I would like to add a function to it that outputs the height of the ball for every second from 0 to the number of seconds specified by the user.

What would I use to do this and how? All other aspects of the program are completed. Currently in existence:

```
double t_height; //User specified height from which ball is dropped
int seconds;     //User specified number of seconds
double distance; //Distance fallen after specified number of seconds
double b_height; //Height of ball after a given number of seconds
```

The above is all solved for, just the variables I'm using. Thanks for the time.

If it helps, here's the 25 or so lines of code I have already.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "constant.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Put tower height meters \n";
    double t_height;
    cin >> t_height;

    cout << "Put number of seconds here \n";
    double seconds;
    cin >> seconds;

    double distance{ constant::g*seconds*seconds / 2 };

    double b_height{ t_height - distance };
    if (distance > t_height)
        b_height = 0;

     cout << "After " << seconds << " seconds the ball is at " << b_height << " meters above the ground. \n";

    return 0;
}
```

(constant.h is just a header file specifying physical and mathematical constants)

Comment: You seem to have it almost working. Just move the lines of code that compute `b_height` to a function.

Comment: I appreciate the interest. It actually is working just fine, however the question above asks about adding a specific function that I don't have knowledge of yet. Thanks for reading though.

Comment: This might help: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/

Comment: Haha, I apologize for the lack of clarity. I'm familiar with how to create and call a function. (Sorry hit enter, give me a sec to edit)
Cont'd:
The key part of the question is this "I would like to add a function to it that outputs the height of the ball for every second from 0 to the number of seconds specified by the user."

Currently I happened upon a "while" loop which I hadn't seen before and am in the process of implementing one. I'll edit the question and close it if possible once I have some success.

Comment: Do the first step, which is to put the code that calculates the height into a function.  The loop (for or while) is the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of skimming another section, I found the "while" loop, and had success implementing this - without creating another function.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "constant.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Put tower height meters \n";
    double t_height;
    cin >> t_height;

    cout << "Put number of seconds here \n";
    int seconds;
    cin >> seconds;

    int count{ 0 };
    while (count <= seconds)
    {
        double distance{ constant::g*count*count / 2 }; //Modified from original to include int count as the new second, as at the end of the loop, count is increased by one for each run.

        double b_height{ t_height - distance };
        if (distance > t_height)
        {
            b_height = 0;
        }
        cout << "After " << count << " seconds the ball is at " << b_height << " meters above the ground. \n";

        count = count + 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If there's anything I can do to make the program more efficient (including more advanced tips and tricks) please comment so I can build on the knowledge I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A way of modifying your code can be like this :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "constant.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double       t_height;
    int          seconds;
    int          count = 0;

    cout << "Put tower height meters \n";
    cin  >> t_height;

    cout << "Put number of seconds here \n";
    cin  >> seconds;

    while (count <= seconds)
    {
        double distance = (constant::g * count * count) / 2; 
        double b_height = t_height - distance;

        if (distance > t_height){
            b_height = 0;
        }
        cout << "After " << count << " seconds the ball is at " << b_height << " meters above the ground. \n";

        count++;
    }
}
```

You already solved the problem and this version is just changing the way the code is written and it is not improving the algorithm of the process.

Comment: Thank you! I've looked over a couple of the things I haven't learned yet, and well. Now I know them.